# Pandas - find periods of time with gaps of less than 30 mins

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to hours per person per day where a person has multiple shifts but a break between shifts isn't counted if it is over 30 minutes.

Given input like this -

```
data = {'EmployeeName':['Alice', 'Alice', 'Bob','Bob','Bob',],
       'ActualStartDateTime':['2021/03/01 09:00', '2021/03/02 09:00', '2021/03/01 09:00', '2021/03/01 09:45', '2021/03/01 11:00',],
       'ActualEndDateTime'  :['2021/03/01 10:00', '2021/03/02 10:00', '2021/03/01 09:30', '2021/03/01 10:15', '2021/03/01 11:30',],
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['EmployeeName','ActualStartDateTime', 'ActualEndDateTime'])

EmployeeName    ActualStartDateTime ActualEndDateTime
0   Alice   2021/03/01 09:00    2021/03/01 10:00
1   Alice   2021/03/02 09:00    2021/03/02 10:00
2   Bob     2021/03/01 09:00    2021/03/01 09:30
3   Bob     2021/03/01 09:45    2021/03/01 10:15
4   Bob     2021/03/01 11:00    2021/03/01 11:30
```

I want to produce a dataframe like this -

```
EmployeeName    Date    Hours
0   Alice   2021/03/01  1.00
1   Alice   2021/03/02  1.00
2   Bob     2021/03/01  1.50
```

How can I do this without iterating through each row?

Thanks

**Clarifications**

- I'd like to vectorise this rather than iterate through each row individually but I can't work out how to.
- Shifts don't cross day boundaries
- Bob worked 1.25 hours 0900-1015 and another 0.5 hours 1100-1130. He doesn't get paid for 1015-1100 because that is a gap of over 30 mins.

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "without iterating...".  You *must* access the data in each row to produce the desired output.  Are you asking how to do this without an *explicit* iteration over the rows?  If so, you first need to apply `groupby` to partition the records for each employee.  Can a shift cross day boundaries (midnight)?  If not, then you also `groupby` rows with the gap sufficiently close.  Since you haven't given us any code yet, I suspect that you need to repeat your PANDAS tutorial before you finish your question here.

Comment: Looks like you just want to find the time worked each day by employee. I don't understand any of the 30 minute requirements as bob gets a single 1.5 hour shift even though there's a 15 minute, and 45 minute break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you break down the problem into steps, it does not become very challenging:

```
from datetime import timedelta
import pandas as pd

data = {'EmployeeName':['Alice', 'Alice', 'Bob','Bob','Bob',],
       'ActualStartDateTime':['2021/03/01 09:00', '2021/03/02 09:00', '2021/03/01 09:00', '2021/03/01 09:45', '2021/03/01 11:00',],
       'ActualEndDateTime'  :['2021/03/01 10:00', '2021/03/02 10:00', '2021/03/01 09:30', '2021/03/01 10:15', '2021/03/01 11:30',],
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['EmployeeName','ActualStartDateTime', 'ActualEndDateTime'])
df['ActualStartDateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.ActualStartDateTime)
df['ActualEndDateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.ActualEndDateTime)
```

Calculate the gap between the start time in current row and the end time in previous row, grouped by employee:

```
df['break'] = df.ActualStartDateTime - df.groupby("EmployeeName").ActualEndDateTime.shift()
```

Compute break time that is eligible to be added to actual time worked:

```
df['break_eligible_for_pay'] = df['break'].apply(lambda x: x if x <= timedelta(minutes=30) else timedelta())
```

Compute total time eligible for pay, in hours:

```
df['total_shift'] = ((df.ActualEndDateTime - df.ActualStartDateTime + df.break_eligible_for_pay).dt.seconds) / 3600
```

Add up shifts by employee-date:

```
final_df = df.groupby(['EmployeeName', df.ActualStartDateTime.dt.date]).total_shift.sum().reset_index(name="Total_Person_Date_Time")
```

Final result:

```
    EmployeeName    ActualStartDateTime Total_Person_Date_Time
0   Alice           2021-03-01          1.00
1   Alice           2021-03-02          1.00
2   Bob             2021-03-01          1.75
```

Answer (score 0):

That's brilliant, thanks Alex. The groupby is key to vectorising it all and that's where I was stuck.

Final version attaching break to the end of a shift and using pd.Timedelta -

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'EmployeeName':['Alice', 'Alice', 'Bob','Bob','Bob',],
       'ActualStartDateTime':['2021/03/01 09:00', '2021/03/02 09:00', '2021/03/01 09:00', '2021/03/01 09:45', '2021/03/01 11:00',],
       'ActualEndDateTime'  :['2021/03/01 10:00', '2021/03/02 10:00', '2021/03/01 09:30', '2021/03/01 10:15', '2021/03/01 11:30',],
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['EmployeeName','ActualStartDateTime', 'ActualEndDateTime'])
df['ActualStartDateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.ActualStartDateTime)
df['ActualEndDateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.ActualEndDateTime)
df['break'] = df.groupby("EmployeeName").ActualStartDateTime.shift(-1) - df.ActualEndDateTime
df['break_eligible_for_pay'] = df['break'].apply(lambda x: x if x <= pd.Timedelta(minutes=30) else pd.Timedelta(seconds=0))
df['total_shift'] = ((df.ActualEndDateTime - df.ActualStartDateTime + df.break_eligible_for_pay).dt.seconds) / 3600
final_df = df.groupby(['EmployeeName', df.ActualStartDateTime.dt.date]).total_shift.sum().reset_index(name="Total_Person_Date_Time")
```

(posted as an answer because it's too long for comment)

Comment: Glad to help. Please consider accepting my answer if you are satisfied.